# Why I can't get the data on a new page from mysql via Vue?

Tags: mysql, database, express, vue.js

Apologies for asking what looks like a common question but I cannot seem to be able to achieve.

I would like to click 'a' tag and open a new page to show an article according to the id from MySQL Database. But I got 500.

Could anyone tell me what's the matter with my codding? Thank You.

Here is the 'a' tag

```
 <article v-for='item in dataGroup'>
      <a :href="'http://localhost:8090/articlePage.html?articlePage?id='+item.ID" :name='pageId' target="__blank">
        <h4>{{item.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{item.intro}}</p>
      </a>
 </article>
```

I use Vue-resource to send the 'get' request

```
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      dataGroup: [],
    },
    methods: {
      renderArticle(url) {
        this.$http.get(url, {

        }).then((res) => {
          this.dataGroup = res.data;
        }, (res) => {
          alert(res.status)
        })

      },
    },
    created() {
      this.renderArticle('/articlePage')

    }
  })
```

Here is my server code

```
module.exports = () => {
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.query(`SELECT * FROM articles_table WHERE ID='${pageId.id}'`, (err, page) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('database error').end();
    } else {
      res.send(page);
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: what's the error you get from `console.error(err);` ?

Comment: the request didn't arrive server. The 500 status is received from vue-resource 'alert(res.status)' @Jacob Goh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have not defined a server side route for `articlePage`
2. You're never actually sending `pageId` to the server, so therefore you can't utilize it in your query as the server doesn't know what that variable is, let alone how to access `id` off of it.
3. You do not have a `catchall (*)` route defined to return a `404` error code, so the server is (presumably) responding with a `500` server error because it doesn't know how to handle the request.

**Edit**

Your URL doesn't make sense to me, it should be something like:

```
https://localhost:8090/articlePage.html?articlePageId='+item.ID
```

Then on the server side you can access any variables in the query string off of the request, like below:

```
req.query.articlePageId
```

The `req.query` part is where the magic happens

Comment: I have tried to define a server side route for articlePage, but it still sends me 500 status. The 'pageId' is 'item.ID' in this URL "http://localhost:8090/articlePage.html?articlePage?id='+item.ID". Is it correct?

Comment: @Sylvia In the same terminal window that is operating your `express` server, you should be seeing a more specific message. I would also suggest changing your returned arguments to `(err, req, res, next)`, so you can get the entire stack trace with `console.error(err.stack)`

Comment: sorry, but here the request can't arrive the server...@Ohgodwhy

Comment: @Sylvia A `500` error response can't just appear out of thin air. Only a server can respond with a `500` **internal server error**. So there's some server, at the very least, that's matching this request and responding accordingly. Do you have some type of proxy setup?

Comment: Nope... I haven't that, I also have tried to write an 'alert(xx)' in server code, but it didn't appear. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: @Sylvia What console are you looking at here? You can't `alert` and get it to appear on your website. You need to look at the **terminal window** where you're running, what I presume is, `node ./server.js`

Comment: Thank you, I see!  terminal window shows 'pageId is not defined', could you tell me how to send the 'pageId' to the server? Why the url(http://localhost:8090/articlePage.html?articlePage?id='+item.ID) can not send the pageId?@Ohgodwhy

Comment: @Sylvia Updated my answer for you. Hopefully that solves it!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.@Ohgodwhy

Comment: I have tried 'console.log(req.query.articlePageId)' , but terminal window show a 'undefined' message@Ohgodwhy